# How can I fix this max-height Javascript Issue or use CSS to get the same results?

Tags: javascript, css, interspire-shopping-cart

I'm working with the Interspire shopping cart and there is a bit of code in common.js that controls the height of the product display boxes for things like "featured products". It makes it so all of the elements are at the same height.  That makes everything look nice but this doesn't seem to work in Firefox.  The product displays look great in Chrome and IE but on firefox the box heights expand to 4000+ pixels!  Even more weird is that sometimes if I hit the refresh button, it fixes and shows correctly. I can hit refresh again and it's back to being messed up. Site testers are experiencing the same problem.

[image]

I removed the bit of code and set the height of the boxes in the CSS file but then the elements are all of different heights and the display doesn't look very good. So I put the code back and I'm stumped.

I'm thinking I'll have to get rid of this code and try to achieve the same result via CSS only. Is this possible?  I'm unsure how to do that so that all the elements are at the same height relative to each other.

The comment the Interpsire coder put in is that this bit of code is a 'hack job'...

```
// Ensure that all product lists are the same height
function setProductListHeights(imgName, className) {
    // hack job putting this here but it needs to be reused by search ajax pager
    if (typeof(DesignMode) != 'undefined') {
        return;
    }

    if (typeof imgName != 'undefined') {
        if (typeof loadedImages[imgName] != 'undefined') {
            return;
        }

        loadedImages[imgName] = true;
    }

    setProductThumbHeight();
    /**
     * Sets the height of the elements passed in to match that of the one that
     * has the greatest height.
     *
     * @param ele The element(s) to adjust the height for.
     * @return void
     */
    function setHeight(ele) {
        var ele       = $(ele),
            maxHeight = 0;

        ele
            // reset the height just in case it was set by the stylesheet so
            // we can detect it
            .css('height', 'auto')
            // get the one with the greatest height
            .each(function() {
                if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
                    maxHeight = $(this).height();
                }
            })
            // and set them all to the greatest height
            .css('height', maxHeight);
    }

    if (!className) {
        className = '.Content';
    }

    setHeight(className + ' .ProductList:not(.List) li .ProductDetails');

    if (typeof imgName != 'undefined') {
        setHeight(className + ' .ProductList:not(.List) li .ProductPriceRating:has(img[src$='+imgName+'])');
    }

    setHeight(className + ' .ProductList:not(.List) li');
 }
```

Thanks so much! I've been trying to fix this for a little while, particularly for some custom sales panels I created.

Comment: Do you have a link to the page?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't share the link but was hoping someone might spot something off hand. If you need more info about the css or something I can add the info.

Answer (score 0):

The only potential issue that I can see is with the following:

.css('height', maxHeight);

No unit of measurement is specified, try appending the unit of measurement to maxHeight:

.css('height', maxHeight + 'px');

Comment: Thanks. It did't fix the problem, unfortunately.  :) Hopefully we can get to the bottom of this. I guess, worse case scenario is to remove this code and have everything uneven but it sure is ugly. :)

Comment: I'll check shortly as soon as I get home and let you know. :) Thanks.

Comment: Another suggestion; try removing .css('height', 'auto') from the equation.

Comment: hmmm nothing came up for me on the console thing in firebug. Thanks for the thoughts. I ended up changing 'auto' to 250. That seems to look fine. Removing that line cut off text at the bottom.

Comment: The method .css('height', 'auto') is just a form of reset (if pre-defined styles exist in the stylesheet), it shouldn't impact height detection...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing 'auto' of the line .css('height', 'auto') to 250. That seems to look fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have set a fixed height but also introduced a variation on the set height function to prevent the add to basket links being pushed off the screen.

There is probably a more concise way of doing this but I was short on time.

```
function setHeight(ele) {
    var ele       = $(ele),
        maxHeight = 0;

    ele
        // reset the height just in case it was set by the stylesheet so
        // we can detect it
        .css('height', 'auto')
        // get the one with the greatest height
        /*
        .each(function() {
            if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
                maxHeight = $(this).height();
            }
        })
        */
        // and set them all to the greatest height
        //.css('height', maxHeight);
        // edited as was causing 700+ height in firefox
        .css('height', 250);
}

function setHeightProdDetails(ele) {
    //variant function added for speed to correct firefox height issue
    var ele       = $(ele),
        maxHeight = 0;

    ele
        // reset the height just in case it was set by the stylesheet so
        // we can detect it
        .css('height', 'auto')
        .css('height', 60);
}

setHeightProdDetails('.Content .ProductList:not(.List) li .ProductDetails');

if (typeof imgName != 'undefined') {
    setHeight('.Content .ProductList:not(.List) li .ProductPriceRating:has(img[src$='+imgName+'])');
}

setHeight('.Content .ProductList:not(.List) li');
```

Answer (score -1):

Same problem here. I assume that Interspire have fixed this already, and my client is using an old version.  I tried the suggested solution of hardcoding the height size, but then I lost the "Add to Cart" link under the product - I think because this function gets called for a number of object sets and the early sets need to be smaller than the later ones.

I'm pretty sure the problem is a timing issue, because when I tracked it through using the FF Developer tools (with a conditional breakpoint to stop when maxHeight blew up over 300) I couldn't reproduce the fault.  My solution which seems to be holding, is to check that I've got a valid number before doing the comparison and for good measure put an upper limit on the size:

```
if (typeof ($(this).height()) == "number" && $(this).height() > maxHeight) {
  if ($(this).height() < 300 ) {
    maxHeight = $(this).height();
  }
}
```